# Não consigo comparar uma média aritmética, para que eu possa usar o select

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou usando o postgresql para fazer o `select` de um atributo chamado `val_unit` de uma tabela de nome `produto`.

Eu uso `having avg(val_unit) > val_unit` ou `where avg(val_unit)` para selecionar apenas os `val_unit` que se mantém dentro da média de todos, mas simplesmente não dá.

Meus `select`s:

```
select descricao_produto from produto where val_unit < avg(val_unit);

select descricao_produto form produto having val_unit < avg(val_unit);
```

Comment: Explique o significado de "simplesmente não dá", se possível dê um exemplo com o resultado obtido e o desejado.

Comment: Está faltando agrupar para poder calcular a média

Comment: Em tese .... select descricao_produto from produto where val_unit < (select avg(val_unit) from produto) ... os abaixo da média